# php-resque : How to pause and stop a worker from php script

Tags: php-resque

PHP-Resque workers can be started from a script with something like

```
passthru("nohup php " . __RESQUE_BIN__ . " >> " . __RESQUE_LOG__ . " 2>&1 &");
```

But how do i pause them, or stop them from a php script ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [README](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/blob/master/README.md), you can send signals to worker processes to do what you ask:

- `QUIT` - Wait for child to finish processing then exit
- `TERM` / `INT` - Immediately kill child then exit
- `USR1` - Immediately kill child but don't exit
- `USR2` - Pause worker, no new jobs will be processed
- `CONT` - Resume worker.

You will need the pid of the worker, you can send a signal with [posix_kill](http://php.net/posix_kill)

Comment: Yes, I did try kill -quit pid , but it works only sometimes and does not work sometimes, any clues ?

Comment: and what's the response to the kill command when it does not work ? Process ID does not exists ? No permission ? Or a job is still processing ?